# How do I calculate the mean of cross_val_score() in a better optimized way?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, cross-validation

I'm using a sample data that consists of 13 features and 304 rows for the sake of training. I'm trying to evaluate the score of the RandomForestClassifier() I used. In order to make the score prediction more precise, I'm adding all the results of cross_val_score() into a list and I get the mean of the numbers in that list. I'm also using a timer to see how long it takes to run it.
Here is the cross_val_score() part of the code:

```
start = time.time()
big_mean = list()
i = 0
while i < 100:
    score = np.mean(cross_val_score(RFC,X,y,cv=5))
    big_mean.append(score)
    i += 1
print(sum(big_mean)/len(big_mean))
end = time.time()
print("Timer: ",end - start)
```

This is what I got:

```
0.8210316939890709
Timer:  75.11970710754395
```

I feel like the code is poorly optimized. If there was more data, it would have taken even more than 75 seconds. What changes would make this a better optimized code?

Comment: you will be able to make it a little faster if you use for loop. Apart from that I don't think you can optimize it more. The problem will still be in the class of O(n)

Comment: I think the main thing that consumes time is the calculation of the cross validation scores with `cross_val_score(RFC,X,y,cv=5)`, which is something you cannot really change anyway. All of the other iterations/calculations barely take any time, given the low amount of required loops/calculations.

Comment: Thanks. Is it meaningful at all that I run the cross validation several times to get a more precise score?

Comment: @cagatay.e.sahin Running cross validation multiple times may be meaningful on model with less stability. Take a look at `big_mean` and change `i` as you want.